# Linear Equations for Common Admission Test (India)

Tags: linear-algebra

This question from linear equations is a question which has appeared in common admission test which is conducted in India for admission into postgraduate management programmes of premier management institutes of the country.

A box contains 5 apples, 7 oranges and 11 pineapples. At least how many fruits should one pick to have at least 4 fruits of the same kind?
A) 9
B) 10
C) 11
D) 12

## LinearEquation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $10$ and I don't see what this has to do with linear algebra.

$9$ is not enough because it could be that you picked $3$ of each fruit.

However $10$ is enough. If by contradiction you picked $10$ fruits yet you didn't pick $4$ of any given fruit then you must've only picked up to $3$ of each but then you only picked up to $9$ fruits by contradiction.

Comment: Pretty much a straight forward pigeonhole problem.

Comment: @DonThousand yes, indeed.

Comment: @Yanko could there be any other explanation? Or any alternative way by which we could arrive at the answer?

Comment: @Yanko: I thinking this is a linear programming problem, which is sometimes subsumed under "linear algebra," at least in the U.S. In India, they call it "linear equations."